# Saving custom object to sdcard (Android)

Tags: android, file, object, save

I'm exploring saving internally versus saving on the sdcard.  Currently, I'm trying to save a custom object (DummyTwice) on the sdcard, like so:

```
            String root = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            File dir = new File(root + PUB_EXT_DIR);
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir,FILE_NAME);

            try {

                DummyTwice dt = new DummyTwice(textEnter.getText().toString());
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
                oos.writeObject(dt);
                oos.close();
                os.close();

                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Object Saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Execution stops at:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
```

Catching the exception:

```
FileNotFoundException e
```

What am I doing wrong? Relevant constants:

```
private final static String PUB_EXT_DIR = /data
private final static String FILE_NAME = /obj.dat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't write directly on the sdcard, and you should use

```
getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

instead of

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

`getExternalFilesDir(null)` returns a private path on the sdcard for your `Activity`, like `/sdcard/Android/data/package.your.app`

Comment: Thanks! Would that be private or public?

Comment: private for your app.